# Issues with no flux boundary conditions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

[image]The no flux boundary conditions are making trouble. How to handle them? 
The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows.

PDE:

```
0.036*D[C[x,y],x]==2.4*10^-10*(D[C[x,y],{x,2}]+D[C[x,y],{y,2}])
```

Boundary conditions:

```
C[0,y]==Piecewise[{{1,H/2<y<=H},{0.5,0<=y<=H/2}}]
(D[C[x,y],x]/.x->1)==0
(D[C[x,y],y]/.y->0)==0
(D[C[x,y],y]/.y->0.005)==0
```

I wrote the following:

```
sol2=NDSolve[{0.036*D[C[x,y],x]==2.4*10^-10*(D[C[x,y],{x,2}]+D[C[x,y],{y,2}]),
              C[0,y]==Piecewise[{{1,H/2<y<=H},{0.5,0<=y<=H/2}}],
              (D[C[x,y],x]/.x->1)==0,(D[C[x,y],y]/.y->0)==0,(D[C[x,y],y]/.y->0.005)==0},
             C,{x,0,1},{y,0,0.005}]
```

The error message shows-The dependent variable in the boundary condition Dirichlet condition need to be linear.
But I noticed that a similar no flux boundary condition works just fine (for a different problem though).

```
sol3=NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],u[0, x] == 0,
              u[t, 0] == Sin[t],(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0)== 0},
              u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

What is the issue in the previous case and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. For your problem, `NDSolve` is using `FiniteElement` for solving the problem (and for your problem `FiniteElement` is the only available method at the moment), and (at least currently) one needs to express b.c. involving derivative with `NeumannValue` when using `FiniteElement`. Just have a look at document of `NeumannValue` by pressing **F1**, and search in this site for more examples.

Comment: BTW, `sol3` works because for this type of problem `MethodOfLines` together with `TensorProductGrid` method, which doesn't require one to express Neumann b.c. as `NeumannValue`, is used.

Comment: Luckily, zero NeumannValue can be eliminated for `FiniteElement` method, so just removing the last 3 b.c.s will resolve your problem.